# Wiring Black White Red to White White Black

Tags: wiring, bathroom, fans

Bought a new bathroom fan/light but the wiring is different from the previous.   House wiring is Black-White-Red, new fan light is White-White-Black.  Both have a ground wire.

Comment: "new fan light is White-White-Black" take a really good look. Are you sure one of those whites isn't gray or pink or light blue or something else?

Comment: Fan wiring seems suspect.  Does it have UL/CSA/ETL listing/label, or a CE label?  Is there any installation instructions?  Picture of the fan and maybe instructions will help, but right now am thinking it should be returned.

Comment: Also, what is the model number of the fan/light? Please edit that information into yuor question.